# androidx Navigation: Too many arguments for @NonNull public open fun

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I am using Navigation Editor in Android Studio to implement `Safe Args`.

I am accepting arguments in one fragment as

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/gameWonFragment"
    android:name="com.example.android.navigation.GameWonFragment"
    android:label="@string/android_trivia"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_game_won">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_gameWonFragment_to_gameFragment"
        app:destination="@id/gameFragment"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/titleFragment">
    </action>
    <argument
        android:name="numQuestions"
        app:argType="integer"
        android:defaultValue="0" />
    <argument
        android:name="numCorrect"
        app:argType="integer"
        android:defaultValue="0" />
 </fragment>
```

And in my Fragment, I am sending arguments as

```
view.findNavController().navigate(GameFragmentDirections.actionGameFragmentToGameWonFragment(numQuestions, questionIndex))
```

But, `GameFragmentDirections.actionGameFragmentToGameWonFragment()` doesn't want to accept arguments. I tried `Clean Project` and `Rebuild Project`.

This is throwing:

```
Too many arguments for @NonNull public open fun actionGameFragmentToGameWonFragment(): GameFragmentDirections.ActionGameFragmentToGameWonFragment defined in com.example.android.navigation.GameFragmentDirections
```

Comment: I have run into the same problem. But I need a default value for my fragment. Is there a solution with default values?

Comment: Hi Jim,Any solutions?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This issue is fixed by **removing** the `android:defaultValue` tag.

So -

```
<argument
    android:name="numQuestions"
    app:argType="integer"/>
<argument
    android:name="numCorrect"
    app:argType="integer"/>
```

Then `Rebuild Project` after making changes.

Comment: Solution worked on my case thx.

Answer (score 14):

This was answered in a similar post here -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60807951/11615237

Basically, you probably need to use the Kotlin version of the plugin like this `apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"`.

Comment: it's working like charm, i thought that safe args was broken!

Answer (score 14):

I have also run into this issue. I was able to retain the `android:defaultValue` argument tag and clear up the "too many arguments" error by obtaining an instance of the appropriate action object, setting the necessary values, and then sending that to the navigate command.

So, for example, this:

```
val actionDetail = GameFragmentDirections.actionGameFragmentToGameWonFragment()
actionDetail.numQuestions = numQuestions
actionDetail.numCorrect = questionIndex
view.findNavController().navigate(actionDetail)
```

rather than this:

```
view.findNavController().navigate(GameFragmentDirections.actionGameFragmentToGameWonFragment(numQuestions, questionIndex))
```

Comment: This is the right solution if you want to set defaultValue for your argument.

Comment: Agree with @Sattar. Use this fix, if you depend on defaultValues

Answer (score 4):

> " Too many arguments for public fun View.findNavController():
>   NavController defined in androidx.navigation "

I encountered the same error.

The confirmed answer didn't solve my problem.

### My solution

File ->  Invalidate Caches/Restart

### Attention

Note that the correct arguments are passed to the correct fragment.

### Sample

```
view.findNavController()
      .navigate(GameFragmentDirections
            .actionGameFragmentToGameWonFragment(numQuestions, questionIndex))
```

Note that the correct fragment is in action.

Thanks.

Comment: This solution worked for me. When adding the plugins in the gradle files, android studio didn't recognize they got updated. Manually syncing and building the project fixed this for me. Thank you mate

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue. I fixed it by putting arguments inside the action tag.

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_gameWonFragment_to_gameFragment"
    app:destination="@id/gameFragment"
    app:popUpTo="@+id/titleFragment">
    <argument
        android:name="numQuestions"
        app:argType="integer" />
    <argument
        android:name="numCorrect"
        app:argType="integer" />
</action>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with the same problem. I am using multi backstack navigation. Each tab has its own graph. In one graph needed destination was absent, what caused the problem. And I solved that by duplicating the destination

Comment: Yes it work for me also but , It tend to unwanted code in other tab navigation graph do you found any other approach?