# Android studio build error in navigation component, action is not abstract and does not implement abstract member actionID

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation

Out of nowhere, the build is crashing with a strange error related to the navigation component even though it used to work before, the error is in the generated class, in my case `NativeLanguageSelectionFragmentDirections`

Here is the error

```
e: C:\Users\David\StudioProjects\android\app\build\generated\source\navigation-args\debug\com\linguistic\linguistic\framework\presentation\loginscreens\ui\main\NativeLanguageSelectionFragmentDirections.kt: (10, 16): Class 'GoToSelectLearningLangAction' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract val actionId: Int defined in androidx.navigation.NavDirections
e: C:\Users\David\StudioProjects\android\app\build\generated\source\navigation-args\debug\com\linguistic\linguistic\framework\presentation\loginscreens\ui\main\NativeLanguageSelectionFragmentDirections.kt: (13, 12): 'getActionId' overrides nothing
e: C:\Users\David\StudioProjects\android\app\build\generated\source\navigation-args\debug\com\linguistic\linguistic\framework\presentation\loginscreens\ui\main\NativeLanguageSelectionFragmentDirections.kt: (15, 12): 'getArguments' overrides nothing
```

And here is the code of the navigation graph

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/first_login_graph.xml"
    app:startDestination="@id/nativeLanguageSelectionFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nativeLanguageSelectionFragment"
        android:name="com.linguistic.linguistic.framework.presentation.loginscreens.ui.main.NativeLanguageSelectionFragment"
        android:label="NativeLanguageSelectionFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/language_selection_fragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/goToSelectLearningLangAction"
            app:destination="@id/learningLanguageSelectionFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
            app:popUpTo="@id/nativeLanguageSelectionFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/learningLanguageSelectionFragment"
        android:name="com.linguistic.linguistic.framework.presentation.loginscreens.ui.main.LearningLanguageSelectionFragment"
        android:label="LearningLanguageSelectionFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/language_selection_fragment">
        <argument
            android:name="nativeLanguageID"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_learningLanguageSelectionFragment_to_welcomeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/welcomeFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
            app:popUpTo="@id/learningLanguageSelectionFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/welcomeFragment"
        android:name="com.linguistic.linguistic.framework.presentation.loginscreens.ui.main.WelcomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_welcome"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_welcome" />
</navigation>
```

I am using

```
 "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5"
 "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5"
```

Comment: did u try invalidating cache and restart?

Comment: Yes, for sure, I tried another android Studio version xD

Comment: That sounds like [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/188564435), but that issue only affects Navigation 2.4.0-alpha01. Are you sure you aren't using Navigation 2.4.0-alpha01?

Comment: yes I am using navigation `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha01` for compose since part of the project is written in android compose

Comment: even after downgrading the dependency mentioned in my previous comment to `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha10`, I am still facing the same issue

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I had this problem too.
Until they release the fix.
Please try this:

```
plugins {
  id("androidx.navigation.safeargs")
}
```

instead of

```
plugins {
  id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin")
}
```

Comment: This was a quick way of working around the same issue for me, thanks. Are there any drawbacks of using the non-Kotlin version?

Comment: You can't use named arguments for example.

Comment: What is the cause of this problem?... What is the difference between these two plugins

Comment: @Venkataramanan, to generate Java language code suitable for Java or mixed Java and Kotlin modules use androidx.navigation.safeargs, to generate Kotlin code suitable for Kotlin-only modules use androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin, from [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args)

Answer (score 41):

As for my case, I had to update Safe Arg plugin as well to get rid of the error message.

```
[build.gradle]
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.4.0-alpha04'
}

[app/build.gradle]
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.0-alpha04'
    api 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.0-alpha04'
    api 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.0-alpha04'
}
```

Comment: This solution works for me. Changing from "2.3.5" to "2.4.0-alpha04" fix my error. Got some warnings ⚠ when building, but works. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I just forgot to update the `nav_version` of `androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version` in the top-level gradle file to the same `nave_version` which is in the module's gradle file.

Answer (score 13):

All of these dependencies

```
androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx
androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx
androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin
```

need to be using the same version - ex: at the time of writing this it's `2.4.0-alpha10`

Answer (score 11):

Since the version [v2.4.0-alpha02](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.4.0-alpha02) was released, this known bug is no longer present.

> Bug Fixes
>
> - Safe Args no longer crashes when attempting to generate direction
>   properties in Kotlin. ([Id2416](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/q/Id2416d7d7c52888fb9ec9bdbb80afcc7d2a1bf3e), [b/188564435](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/188564435))

Comment: Still have this bug, any fix?

Comment: The bug should be fixed by that release. If the problem still persist for you, place your comment on the tracker or create a new issue.

Comment: Got same bug on '2.4.0-alpha06' so it is not fully fixed or some regression happend

Comment: Sounds like a regression bug then @MichałTajchert, in such case I’d bet there’s an existing issue on the tracker.

Answer (score 2):

just update the safe-args dependency to the latest version(>=2.4.0-rc01) too!:

```
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.4.0-rc01"
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case, I get this error for my new `module`. I added the `safe-args classPath` in `build.gradle (project)`

**KOTLIN-DSL:**

```
    "classpath"(group = "androidx.navigation",name = "navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin", version = "2.4.1")
```

without the plunging in my module build.gradle. so I added this on top of `build.gradle`:

```
id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin")
```

**GROOVY:**

```
classpath  "navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin : 2.4.1"
```

and:

```
id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
```

Answer (score 0):

2.4.0-beta02 at this moment available

Answer (score 0):

Please change your build.gradle(:app) file

from

```
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
```

to

```
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
```