# Class 'action' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract val actionId: Int defined in androidx.navigation.NavDirections

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation

I used version `2.4.0-alpha04` to conveniently use `multi-backstack` of `navigation`. ([develop docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation?hl=en#2.4.0-alpha04))

But I got the following error:

```
Class 'ActionDialogToWriteRoutine' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract val actionId: Int defined in androidx.navigation.NavDirections
```

I first searched here to fix the error and found the question with the same error. ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67609911/android-studio-build-error-in-navigation-component-action-is-not-abstract-and-d))

I saw an answer in that link saying that the bug was fixed starting with `v2.4.0-alpha02`.

But I still get the same error.

So I'm posting the question again according to my situation.

What happened?

***build.gradle[app]***

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'

    // safe args
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}

dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.3.1"
    def nav_version = "2.4.0-alpha04"

    // AAC
    implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.4")

    // Navigation Component
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

}
```

***nav_graph.xml***

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/calendar">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/calendar"/>
    <include app:graph="@navigation/list"/>
    <include app:graph="@navigation/write_home"/>
</navigation>
```

***write_home.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/write"
    app:startDestination="@id/home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:name="com.example.writeweight.fragment.WriteRoutineHomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_write_routine_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_write_routine_home" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_home_to_dialog"
            app:destination="@id/dialog" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/dialog"
        android:name="com.example.writeweight.fragment.BodyPartDialogFragment"
        android:label="BodyPartDialogFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_body_part_dialog">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_dialog_to_write_routine"
            app:destination="@id/write_routine" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/write_routine"
        android:name="com.example.writeweight.fragment.WriteRoutineFragment"
        android:label="WriteRoutineFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_writing_routine">
        <argument
            android:name="title"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="@null"/>
        <argument
            android:name="workout"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="@null"/>
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_write_routine_to_workout_tab"
            app:destination="@id/workout_tab" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/workout_tab"
        android:name="com.example.writeweight.fragment.WorkoutListTabFragment"
        android:label="WorkoutListTabFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_workout_list_tab">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_workout_tab_to_write_routine"
            app:destination="@id/write_routine" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

in your app level build.gradle file replace

```
plugins {
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}
```

with

```
plugins {
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
}
```

Comment: So it's a bug in kotlin version of this plugin?

Comment: @paynd I just think its name was changed without proper documentation

Comment: Don't forget to update versions of the navigation libraries that are in the top level gradle file and module's gradle file to the same value! https://stackoverflow.com/a/68331336

Comment: The @JamesBond comment works perfectly to me. The accepted answer works as well but it is just a workaround. Keep both libraries updated with the same version, navigation and safe args gradle plugin.

Answer (score 4):

in your build.gradle file (module).

**Change**

```
plugin{
....
id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'

}
```

To

```
plugin{
.....
id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'

}
```

Comment: what's the difference between this and the accepted answer?